# Can I upgrade to 17.10 maintaining old kernel?

Tags: drivers, upgrade, kernel, amd-graphics, 17.10

I would like to upgrade my system to **Ubuntu 17.10**, but I need to maintain the kernel 4.10 in use, due to amdgpu-pro radeon driver. I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04.3, the latest compatible with **amdgpu-pro** driver.

Is it possible?

I have tried to do a fresh 17.10 install and installed amdgpu-pro driver on it, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 17.10 can be run on the 4.10 kernel.

I do not believe auto-removal of old kernels has been implemented.
After the upgrade, you should have both kernels installed.
Use advanced options in the grub menu, and choose the 4.10 kernel to boot.
Then, remove the new kernel installed.

If the 4.10 kernel is removed you can use the command line to reinstall it and the amdgpu-pro driver.
Download the packages before upgrading so they are handy

NOTE: don't forget the header packages

Comment: Is there a way to block the old kernel and prevent system to removal it?

Comment: not using the standard upgrade methode

Comment: _I do not believe auto-removal of old kernels has been implemented._  How could be sure?

Comment: that means exactly as is stated. However the upgrader will do the upgrade you can not modify it.